# How do I run my C++ code in Heroku?

Tags: c++, heroku

I have a c++ application that I would like to run online. I was considering using Heroku. How would I go about doing this?  Is there an alternative service I should consider isntead?

Comment: Take a look at OpenShit. It's easier to run C++ with it.

Comment: @Adrián Arroyo Calle OpenShift*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku can run anything.

For C++ there are two ways:

- a [c++ buildpack](https://github.com/xHatchx/heroku-buildpack-cpp) that does compile the code while pushing
- through [a docker image](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker)